# How do I force SSL when running an express app behind Apache?

Tags: node.js, apache, .htaccess, ssl, express

I'm running an `express.js` application behind an Apache server using simple rewriting to my app's port:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://localhost:61987/$1 [P]
```

This works as expected.

As the app is expected to go live soon I was trying to add forced SSL connection via `RewriteRule`s as well. The way I have done this in pre-node (i.e. PHP) days was this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} != on
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301, L]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://localhost:61987/$1 [P]
```

Yet, combined with the routing to my express app this gives me a 500 Internal Server error.

What's the correct way to handle this setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a space before `L` in `[R=301, L]`.

Try this code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^ http://localhost:61987%{REQUEST_URI} [P]
```

Assuming `node.js` server on `61987` is also supporting `https`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is creating a circular redirect.

Comment: As per these rules there is no circular redirect (since both are enforcing `https://`), however if there is some redirection to `http://` in your `node.js` then that needs to be looked into.

Comment: I do not mention any protocol at all in my express app and it will also work just fine when I explicitly enter the `https` version of my URLs, so I guess my application does not redirect in any way.

Comment: You can test this easily by commenting out your 2nd rule and see whether any redirection loop exists or not.

Comment: Turns out you were right about the space. Removing this from the example I posted does everything I want. Could not get your example working though. In any case thanks!

Comment: Great to know it worked for you. Other than space removal I have kept my answer pretty much same as what you had.

Comment: I guess the major difference is rewriting to `http://localhost:61987/$1 [P]` instead of `https` (although that does not make too much sense)

Comment: oh yes I made that change after you reported about circular redirect (reverted now).